# Swift defer behaviour

Tags: swift

what is the output:

```
var x = 5
func increment() -> Int {
defer { x += 1 }
return x
}

x = increment()
let result = increment()
print(x, result, x)
```

the answer is 6 5 6,i don't know why result is 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that `increment` always returns the current value of `x`. This is because `defer` is executed after the `return` statement is.

After

```
x = increment()
```

`x` is still 5. `increment` returns 5, increments `x` to 6, then you assign the return value to `x` again.

After

```
let result = increment()
```

`x` becomes 6, and `result` is 5. `increment` returns 5 as before, increments `x` to 6, then you assign the return value to `result`.